# TypeError: Cannot read property 'xp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, typeerror

I don't get any error in Visual Studio Code. But when I run the code on Coursera in browser I get typeerror code "TypeError: Cannot read property 'xp' of undefined". The code runs well with the expected result:

```
class Person{
    constructor(name, age, energy){
        this.name = "Tom";
        this.age = 20;
        this.energy = 100;
    }
    sleep(){
       console.log("Energy has increased to: ", this.energy + 10 );
    }

    doSomethingFun(){
       console.log("Energy has gone downwaed to: ", this.energy - 10);
    }
}
let Person1 = new Person('Tom', 20, 100);
Person1.sleep();
Person1.doSomethingFun();


// Task 2: Code a Worker class
class Worker extends Person{
    constructor(xp, hourlyWage){
        super();
        this.xp = 0;
        this.hourlyWage = 10;
    }
    goToWork(){
        console.log("Experience has improved to: ", this.xp + 10);
    }
}
let Worker1 = new Worker();
Worker1.goToWork(0,10);

// Task 3: Code an intern object, run methods
function intern() {
    intern = new Worker("Bob", 21, 110, 0, 10);
    intern.goToWork();
};
intern();
// Task 4: Code a manager object, methods
function manager() {
    let manager = new Worker("Alice", 30, 120, 100, 30);
    manager.doSomethingFun();
};
manager();
```

Comment: so this is your coursera assignment?

Comment: constructor and call are wrong. You are passing parameters to the method, not the constructor

Answer (score 0):

if you add `return worker;` at the end of the `intern` function, and `return manager;` at the end of the manager function, your error will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First: on Coursera error  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'xp' of undefined" will occur if you try Submit Assignment code not from a file ooprogramming.js.

Second: Your functions don't change values, they only print text.
Try for example:

```
sleep() {
this.energy += 10;
}
```

Try use return:

// Task 3: Code an intern object, run methods

```
function intern() {
var intern = new Worker("Bob", 21, 110, 0, 10);
intern.goToWork();
return intern;
}
```